# How to start a minimal ruby app using Puma or Unicorn?

Tags: ruby, unicorn, thin, puma

I have a very basic ruby example running on Thin, but I would like to know how to translate this example to use Unicorn or Puma as the HTTP server instead. Here is the code I have now:

```
require 'rack'

class HelloWorld
  def talk()
    return "Hello World!"
  end
end

class SomeServer
  def start(server_object, port)
    app = proc do |env|
      [ 200, {"Content-Type" => "text/html"}, [server_object.talk()] ]
    end

    Rack::Handler::Thin::run(app, :Port => port)
  end
end

SomeServer.new.start(HelloWorld.new, 3000)
```

This runs fine and well, but I cannot figure out how to make it run using Puma or Unicorn instead. Most online documentation I find for the two is for Rails apps. How can I utilize the multi-threading capabilities of these servers with this simple program?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

use [sinatra](http://www.sinatrarb.com/).

So to take it step by step first install sinatra and puma gems

```
gem install sinatra

gem install puma
```

then create a file myapp.rb

```
require 'sinatra'
configure { set :server, :puma }

get '/' do
  "Hello World!"
end
```

then run the file

```
ruby myapp.rb
```

by default sinatra listens on 4567 so go to localhost:4567
you can configure puma to listen on a specific port or do a lot of other things using a config file read the [documentation](https://github.com/puma/puma)

Comment: Way late follow up question, is there any way for me to provide configuration options to puma when using this method? For example, I would like to change the min and max number of threads puma runs.

Comment: yes you can have configuration file and specify threads ports and everything and run puma using `puma -C config/puma.rb`

Comment: here's the example config file from the documentation https://github.com/puma/puma/blob/master/examples/config.rb

Comment: The problem when I do this using sinatra is I then have two layers of puma running (the one I started from the command line using the puma command, and then the one sinatra starts up).

Comment: I was able to figure out a configuration that works, thank you very much for your help!

Answer (score 4):

A minimal example that doesn't require additional gems looks like this.

**Using a single file**

Create a puma config file `config.rb` with the following content:

```
app do |env|
  body = 'Hello, World!'
  [200, { 'Content-Type' => 'text/plain', 'Content-Length' => body.length.to_s }, [body]]
end

bind 'tcp://127.0.0.1:3000'
```

and run puma with

```
puma -C /path/to/config.rb
```

That's it.

**Using a configuration and a rackup file**

In the example above, the config file contains the application itself. It makes sense to move the application to a [rackup](http://rack.github.io) file: Create a rackup file `app.ru` with the following content:

```
class HelloWorld
  def call(env)
    body = 'Hello, World!'
   [200, { 'Content-Type' => 'text/plain', 'Content-Length' => body.length.to_s }, [body]]
  end
end

run HelloWorld.new
```

Then update your `config.rb`, removing the app and linking the rackup file instead:

```
rackup '/path/to/app.ru'

bind 'tcp://127.0.0.1:3000'
```

and run puma as before with

```
puma -C /path/to/config.rb
```

The [example configuration file](https://github.com/puma/puma/blob/12d1706ddc71b89ed2ee26275e31c788e94ff541/examples/config.rb) for puma is helpful. (*Update*: This example configuration file is no longer maintained. The authors refer to [dsl.rb](https://github.com/puma/puma/blob/master/lib/puma/dsl.rb) instead.)

Answer (score 3):

Instead of starting your app with `Rack::Handler::Thin`, you should be able to use the Puma Rack handler instead, like this:

```
Rack::Handler::Puma.run(app, :Port =>port)
```

You'd need to also `require 'rack/handler/puma'` after installing the Puma gem.